# finding the day based on date in java - gives incorrect answer

Tags: java, android, date

java.util.Date gives incorrect day as output.

```
    java.util.Date date = new Date(2014,03,01);
    System.out.println("day is" +date.getDay());
```

output : day is 3

actually it should be 7

Update : Thanks a lot I was able to get the output Here is my code

```
    java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    c.clear();
    c.set(year,month,dd);
    System.out.println("day of week "+c.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess you wanted to create the date March 1st 2014. But with your constructor call you create the date April 1st 3914!
The [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) tells you why:

> ```
> A year y is represented by the integer y - 1900.
> A month is represented by an integer from 0 to 11; 0 is January, 1 is February, and so forth; thus 11 is December.
> A date (day of month) is represented by an integer from 1 to 31 in the usual manner.
> ```

EDIT: Also this constructor is deprecated. Use Calendar instead.

Comment: +1. It is `Wed Apr 01 3914` for `new Date( 2014, 03, 01 )` and hence `Day` is `3`.

Answer (score 2):

As per the javadoc of `getDay()`

> Returns the **day of the week** represented by this date. The returned
>   value (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, 3 = Wednesday, 4 =
>   Thursday, 5 = Friday, 6 = Saturday) represents the day of the week
>   that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this
>   Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

so its ***not day of month***. Also note that you are using **deprecated** Date constructor and methods. You can achieve the same using `java.util.Calendar`

Also month `03` is ***not March***, its ***April***

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

Here also the output is 3 because, the date represents April 1st 2014, which is Tuesday and as per `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` doc

> Field number for get and set indicating the day of the week. This
>   field takes values SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY,
>   FRIDAY, and SATURDAY.

And `Calendar.TUESDAY` is `3`

Comment: If `April` then day should return, `2` for `(2014, 03, 01)`. The date `April 1st, 2014` falls on `Tuesday`

Comment: @Ravinder i was wondering the same.. let me try to figure it out